# copyIndex() on resources [] ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Copy Index for multiple blob containers on the azure storage account.

```
"name": "[concat(parameters('storageAccountObject')[copyIndex()].blobServicesProperties.blobServicesContainerProperties[copyIndex()].blobServicesContainerName,'-',copyIndex())]",
```

Parameter.json:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "gcAppEnv": {
            "value": {
                "subscriptionId": "{SubcrptionID}",
                "mmcTenantId": "{TenantID}",
                "oPreFix": "gc",
                "subEnvironment": "Integration",
                "subEnvironmentNicName": "n",
                "networkSettings": {
                    "virtualNetworkResourceGroupName": "{ResourceGroupName}",
                    "virtualNetworks": "/subscriptions/{SubcrptionID}/resourceGroups/{ResourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/{VNet}",
                    "virtualNetworkName": "{VNet}",
                    "metadata": {
                        "description": "Default Settings Created By MGTI.Please Update As Per Your Requirement"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "storageAccountObject": {
            "value": [
                {
                    "type": "AppAndDb",
                    "isNew": true,
                    "storageAccounts_name": "gcappdbstorageacctdev",
                    "storageAccountSkuObject": {
                        "name": "Standard_GRS",
                        "tier": "Standard"
                    },
                    "storageAccountTag": {
                        "responsibleOrg": "Guy Carpenter",
                        "appName": "GCEdge",
                        "typeOfStorageNetworkSupport": "AppAndDb"
                    },
                    "storageAccountKindOff": "StorageV2",
                    "storageAccountProperties": {
                        "NetworkAcls": {
                            "Bypass": "AzureServices",
                            "VNetSubNetRule": [
                                {
                                    "subnets": "/subscriptions/{SubcrptionID}/resourceGroups/{ResourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/{VNet}/subnets/{SubNet-APP}",
                                    "subnetsaction": "Allow",
                                    "subnetsstate": "Succeeded"
                                },
                                {
                                    "subnets": "/subscriptions/{SubcrptionID}/resourceGroups/{ResourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/{VNet}/subnets/{SubNet-DB}",
                                    "subnetsaction": "Allow",
                                    "subnetsstate": "Succeeded"
                                }
                            ],
                            "IPRules": [
                                {
                                    "value": "205.156.84.229/32"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "205.156.136.229/32"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "13.86.33.223"
                                }
                            ],
                            "DefaultAction": "Deny"
                        },
                        "SupportsHttpsTrafficOnly": true,
                        "AccessTier": "Hot"
                    },
                    "blobServicesProperties": {
                        "blobServicesName": "default",
                        "corsProperties": {
                            "corsRules": [
                                {
                                    "allowedOrigins": [
                                        "*"
                                    ],
                                    "allowedMethods": [
                                        "OPTIONS",
                                        "GET",
                                        "HEAD"
                                    ],
                                    "maxAgeInSeconds": 60,
                                    "exposedHeaders": [
                                        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"
                                    ],
                                    "allowedHeaders": [
                                        "Content-Type",
                                        "Authorization",
                                        "x-timestamp"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "BlobServiceSoftDeleteRetentionPolicy": {
                            "enabled": false,
                            "days": 365
                        },
                        "BlobServiceSoftAutomaticSnapshotPolicy": false,
                        "blobServicesContainerProperties": [
                            {
                                "blobServicesContainerName": "gc-app-container-blob",
                                "PublicAccess": "Container",
                                "blobServicesContainerImmutabilityProperties": {
                                    "immutabilityPeriodSinceCreationInDays": 10
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "blobServicesContainerName": "gc-db-container-blob",
                                "PublicAccess": "Blob",
                                "blobServicesContainerImmutabilityProperties": {
                                    "immutabilityPeriodSinceCreationInDays": 10
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "blobServicesContainerName": "gc-web-container-blob",
                                "PublicAccess": "None",
                                "blobServicesContainerImmutabilityProperties": {
                                    "immutabilityPeriodSinceCreationInDays": 10
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Deployment.json :

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "gcAppEnv": {
            "type": "Object"
        },
        "storageAccountObject": {
            "type": "Array"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
            "apiVersion": "2019-04-01",
            "copy": {
                "name": "storageAccountObjectCopy",
                "count": "[length(parameters('storageAccountObject'))]",
                "mode": "serial"
            },
            "name": "[parameters('storageAccountObject')[copyIndex()].storageAccounts_name]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "tags": "[parameters('storageAccountObject')[copyIndex()].storageAccountTag]",
            "sku": "[parameters('storageAccountObject')[copyIndex()].storageAccountSkuObject]",
            "kind": "[parameters('storageAccountObject')[copyIndex()].storageAccountKindOff]",
            "properties": {
                "networkAcls": {
                    "bypass": "[parameters('storageAccountObject')[copyIndex()].storageAccountProperties.NetworkAcls.Bypass]",
                    "ipRules": [],
                    "copy": [
                        {
                            "name": "virtualNetworkRules",
                            "count": "[length(parameters('storageAccountObject')[copyIndex()].storageAccountProperties.NetworkAcls.VNetSubNetRule)]",
                            "input": {
                                "id": "[parameters('storageAccountObject')[copyIndex()].storageAccountProperties.NetworkAcls.VNetSubNetRule[copyIndex('virtualNetworkRules')].subnets]",
                                "action": "[parameters('storageAccountObject')[copyIndex()].storageAccountProperties.NetworkAcls.VNetSubNetRule[copyIndex('virtualNetworkRules')].subnetsaction]",
                                "state": "[parameters('storageAccountObject')[copyIndex()].storageAccountProperties.NetworkAcls.VNetSubNetRule[copyIndex('virtualNetworkRules')].subnetsstate]"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "defaultAction": "[parameters('storageAccountObject')[copyIndex()].storageAccountProperties.NetworkAcls.DefaultAction]"
                },
                "supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": true,
                "encryption": {
                    "services": {
                        "file": {
                            "enabled": true
                        },
                        "blob": {
                            "enabled": true
                        }
                    },
                    "keySource": "Microsoft.Storage"
                },
                "accessTier": "[parameters('storageAccountObject')[copyIndex()].storageAccountProperties.AccessTier]"
            },
            "resources": [
                {
                    "type": "blobServices",
                    "apiVersion": "2019-04-01",
                    "name": "[parameters('storageAccountObject')[copyIndex()].blobServicesProperties.blobServicesName]",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', parameters('storageAccountObject')[copyIndex()].storageAccounts_name)]"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "cors": {
                            "copy": [
                                {
                                    "name": "corsRules",
                                    "count": "[length(parameters('storageAccountObject')[copyIndex()].blobServicesProperties.corsProperties.corsRules)]",
                                    "input": {
                                        "copy": [
                                            {
                                                "name": "allowedOrigins",
                                                "count": "[length(parameters('storageAccountObject')[copyIndex()].blobServicesProperties.corsProperties.corsRules[copyIndex()].allowedOrigins)]",
                                                "input": [
                                                    "[parameters('storageAccountObject')[copyIndex()].blobServicesProperties.corsProperties.corsRules[copyIndex()].allowedOrigins[copyIndex()]]"
                                                ]
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "name": "allowedMethods",
                                                "count": "[length(parameters('storageAccountObject')[copyIndex()].blobServicesProperties.corsProperties.corsRules[copyIndex()].allowedMethods)]",
                                                "input": [
                                                    "[parameters('storageAccountObject')[copyIndex()].blobServicesProperties.corsProperties.corsRules[copyIndex()].allowedMethods[copyIndex()]]"
                                                ]
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "name": "exposedHeaders",
                                                "count": "[length(parameters('storageAccountObject')[copyIndex()].blobServicesProperties.corsProperties.corsRules[copyIndex()].exposedHeaders)]",
                                                "input": [
                                                    "[parameters('storageAccountObject')[copyIndex()].blobServicesProperties.corsProperties.corsRules[copyIndex()].exposedHeaders[copyIndex()]]"
                                                ]
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "name": "allowedHeaders",
                                                "count": "[length(parameters('storageAccountObject')[copyIndex()].blobServicesProperties.corsProperties.corsRules[copyIndex()].allowedHeaders)]",
                                                "input": [
                                                    "[parameters('storageAccountObject')[copyIndex()].blobServicesProperties.corsProperties.corsRules[copyIndex()].allowedHeaders[copyIndex()]]"
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "maxAgeInSeconds": "[parameters('storageAccountObject')[copyIndex()].blobServicesProperties.corsProperties.corsRules[copyIndex()].maxAgeInSeconds]"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "deleteRetentionPolicy": {
                            "enabled": "[parameters('storageAccountObject')[copyIndex()].blobServicesProperties.BlobServiceSoftDeleteRetentionPolicy.enabled]",
                            "days": "[parameters('storageAccountObject')[copyIndex()].blobServicesProperties.BlobServiceSoftDeleteRetentionPolicy.days]"
                        },
                        "automaticSnapshotPolicyEnabled": "[parameters('storageAccountObject')[copyIndex()].blobServicesProperties.BlobServiceSoftAutomaticSnapshotPolicy]"
                    },
                    "resources": [
                        {
                            "type": "containers",
                            "name": "[concat(parameters('storageAccountObject')[copyIndex()].blobServicesProperties.blobServicesContainerProperties[copyIndex()].blobServicesContainerName,'-',copyIndex())]",
                            "apiVersion": "2019-04-01",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                "[concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/',parameters('storageAccountObject')[copyIndex()].storageAccounts_name,'/blobServices/default')]"
                            ],
                            "properties": {
                                "publicAccess": "[parameters('storageAccountObject')[copyIndex()].blobServicesProperties.blobServicesContainerProperties[copyIndex()].PublicAccess]"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

```
"blobServicesContainerProperties": [
                            {
                                "blobServicesContainerName": "gc-app-container-blob",
                                "PublicAccess": "Container",
                                "blobServicesContainerImmutabilityProperties": {
                                    "immutabilityPeriodSinceCreationInDays": 10
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "blobServicesContainerName": "gc-db-container-blob",
                                "PublicAccess": "Blob",
                                "blobServicesContainerImmutabilityProperties": {
                                    "immutabilityPeriodSinceCreationInDays": 10
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "blobServicesContainerName": "gc-web-container-blob",
                                "PublicAccess": "None",
                                "blobServicesContainerImmutabilityProperties": {
                                    "immutabilityPeriodSinceCreationInDays": 10
                                }
                            }
                        ]
```

There was no exception but failed to create resources. It just creates one container instead of 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can't use a copy loop for a child resource. To create more than
>   one instance of a resource that you typically define as nested within
>   another resource, you must instead create that resource as a top-level
>   resource. You define the relationship with the parent resource through
>   the type and name properties.

Reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-multiple#iteration-for-a-child-resource

just create a separate container resources:

```
{
    "name": "[concat(parameters('storageAccountObject')[copyIndex()].storageAccounts_name, '/default/', parameters('containerName'))]",
    "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers",
    "apiVersion": "2018-07-01",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[parameters('storageAccountName')]"
    ]
}
```

Comment: What if I have to create a list of containers?

Comment: weird, I thought I answered this comment. anyway, just use copy like you normally would. if this answer helped you, consider accepting it

Comment: My requirment is to use copyIndex() of Some copyIndex().
XYZ[copyIndex()].xyz[copyIndex()]

Comment: you cannot do that. you can work around with using a nested deployment and having a resource copy inside the nested deployment. no other way of doing that